# How to reorder time on the y-axis so midnight is in the center

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am graphing day (x-axis) by time in minutes (y-axis) using `geom_raster` to create an actogram. I want the y-axis to start at 12 noon and go down to midnight and then back up to noon (12pm, 11am, 10am, 9am, 8am, 7am, 6am, 5am, 4am, 3am, 2am, 1am, 0, 11pm, 10pm, 9pm, 8pm, 7pm, 6pm, 5pm, 4pm, 3pm, 2pm, 1pm 12pm), so midnight will be in the center. I have absolutely no idea how to do this.

I have tried to turn the data into a factor and order it:

```
x <- seq(11.55, 0, -0.05)
y <- seq(23.55, 12.00, -0.05)
z <- c(x,y)
```

but the problem is I have a lot of duplicate values because I am working with 24 days worth of data...

This is my code without rearranging the y-axis:

```
ggplot(LIA_20, aes(x = date, y = time))+
  geom_raster(data = LIA_20, aes(fill = Sv_mean))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = matlab.like(100), na.value = "white",
                       limits = c(-140, -70))+
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(2, 23), breaks = 3:22)+
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0))+

  coord_fixed(ratio = 0.00005)+
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
        legend.position = "bottom")+
  labs(x = "Day (May 2018)", y = "Time of day, UTC", fill = "Sv (dB)")+ 
  guides(fill = guide_colourbar(title.position = "bottom", 
                                title.hjust = 0.5))
```

Comment: Your ggplot code does not run. To start with, you have not provided the LIA_20 dataset. Can you provide a reproducible example?